# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: trim(): Argument #1 ($string) at \wp-includes\class-wp-query.php

Tags: errors

I am using a form to submit table inserted values using `<input name=[]>` as `$_POST` to a PHP page. It's a template page of wordpress and I am getting an error.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: table page
*/
get_header();
global $wpdb;
$names= $wpdb-> get_results('select stdName FROM wp_nis_student');
?>
<form action="" method="post" >
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>English</th>
                <th>Maths</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php foreach($names as $name ){?>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $name->stdName;>"/</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="Engmark[]"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="Mathmark[]"/></td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    <button  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['Engmark']) && isset($_POST['Mathmark'])){
         echo "Names: <br/>";
            foreach ( $_POST["name"] as $name ) 
              echo $name . "<br/>";
            echo "<br/><br/>" .
                 "English : <br/>";
            foreach ( $_POST["Engmark"] as $eng ) 
              echo $eng . "<br/>";

              echo "<br/><br/>" .
                 "Maths: <br/>";
            foreach ( $_POST["Mathmark"] as $mat ) 
              echo $mat . "<br/>";
          }
     else echo "Error: no data";
        }
?>
```

And I am getting this error because am calling **isset($_POST['submit'])**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: trim(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of
> type string, array given in ..\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php on line
> 811

Then a made change at the line 811 in class-wp-query.php **$qv['name']  = trim( $qv['name'] ); to $qv['name'] = trim( $qv['name[]'] );**  it worked fine but i start getting warning on the website

`Warning: Undefined array key "name[]" in ..\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php on line 811`

How can I resolve it?

Comment: `name` is a reserved term in WordPress and using it like this is causing conflicts because WordPress expects it to be a string. You’ll need to use a different name for that field.

Comment: @JacobPeattie you should have left that as an answer :)

Comment: Also Minh, none of your `echo` calls have escaping, so `5` may be a valid value, but so is `"/><script>alert("Minh didn't write secure code");</script>`. Look up `esc_attr`, `esc_url` and `esc_html`. Same with `$eng` and `$name` and all the other places you `echo` a variable and trust it's safe without checking

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you. the `name` was the issue and it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `name[]`, specifically `name`. When you are choosing what to name your inputs, keep in mind that WordPress itself has inputs and by choosing `"name"` you're reusing something that's already in use.

E.g. `example.com/mypage` is converted into `index.php?name=mypage` behind the scenes, and used to fill up the main query. By reusing `name` you're putting something in the system that isn't meant to be there. It's expecting a string because page and post names are strings, but your form uses an array.

So rename your `name[]` input to something else that isn't already reserved. You can look up the `WP_Query` documentation to see all the options that class takes ( and that you should not use )